# problem on converting data to numpy array

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have pandas data frame

```
data=df.loc[[0]] 
print(data)
0    3.5257,3.5257,3.5257000000000005,3.5257,3.5257...
Name: testdata, dtype: object
```

I need to convert it to numpy array and want to plot the figure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the .values attribute of the dataframe to convert it to a numpy array, and then use the numpy array to plot the figure. Here's an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = df.loc[[0]].values[0]
plt.plot(data)
plt.show()
```

Note that in the above code, df.loc[[0]].values[0] is used to extract the numpy array from the dataframe, as the output of df.loc[[0]] is still a dataframe.
You can also use the .to_numpy() method to convert the dataframe to numpy array.

```
data = df.to_numpy()
plt.plot(data)
plt.show()
```

Also make sure that you have the matplotlib library imported and the data is of numerical values, otherwise you will get an error while plotting.

Comment: Thanks @Rezuana

Comment: my data comes something like this '3.5257,3.5257,3.5257,3.5257,3.5257,3.5257' after using data = df.loc[[0]].values[0] and the plt.show() gives the blank plot